# change detection of property in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

In app.component.ts, I have a property called current.

```
export class appComponent {
  current = 0;
}
```

In some of my methods I changed this property

```
previous() {
  this.current -= 1
}
next() {
  this.current += 1
}
```

Now, I want to run a set of command when current property is changed. I can do it by appending those command after changes.

```
previous() {
  this.current -= 1;
  this.runCommands();

}
next() {
  this.current += 1;
  this.runCommands();
}
```

Everything works just fine. But see, it seems very messy calling this method every time this property changes. What I want to do run a change detection function what run my command like:

```
this.current.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.runCommand());
```

is it possible with any simpler way in angular?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to make `current` an `Observable` via a `BehaviorSubject`. Ideally, these would exist in an injectable service and then the components that rely on the value of `current` would be subscribed via the injected service.

Setting up the `Observable` would look like

```
   private _current = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
   public readonly current = this._current.asObservable();
```

and then we can subscribe to current in the components (in this example, the one it lives in) that need to like

```
   this.current.subscribe(val => {
        // do stuff here
    })
```

Any time we wish to change the value of `current` and fire the event for anything subscribed to it we do this like

```
    this._current.next(123);  // anything subscribed receives the value of 123
```

You can do this in your component, but the best practice is to put the `Observable` in your service layer.

To achieve your desired use case of incrementing the value by 1 or -1, the `BehaviorSubject` function `getValue()` will come in handy by telling you the current value stored in the `Observable`.

```
    this._current.next(++this._current.getValue()) // increment 1
    this._current.next(--this._current.getValue()) // increment -1
    // etc...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clean answer. It saved my day

Comment: Even better use setters and getters.   public set current(value: int) { _current.next(value);}  public get current () { return this._current.getValue(); }